# WORDPRESS postexpiratorプラグインで指定した期限の近い順に並べたい

Tags: php, wordpress

現在、ワードプレスでサイトを構築しております。

postexpiratorというプラグインを使用し、記事に有効期限をつけております。

その期限が近い順に並びかえて一覧表示させたいのですが、何かいい方法はありませんか？